# Cannot get multi-line regex to match string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading an HTML file, trying to get some information out of it.  I've tried HTML parsers, but can't figure out how to use them to get key text out.  The original reads the html file, but this version is a minimal working example for StackOverflow purposes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.036;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':default';
use Devel::Confess 'color';

sub regex_test ( $string, $regex ) {
    if ($string =~ m/$regex/s) {
        say "$string matches $regex";
    } else {
        say "$string doesn't match $regex";
    }
}
# the HTML text is $s
my $s = '      rs577952184 was merged into
      
        <a target="_blank"
           href="rs59222162">rs59222162</a>
      
';

regex_test ( $s, 'rs\d+ was merged into.*\<a target="_blank".+href="rs(\d+)/');
```

however, this doesn't match.

I think that the problem is the newline after "merged into" isn't matching.

How can I alter the above regex to match `$s`?

Comment: I think you need to escape the backslashes in the string.

Comment: @Barmar but the original HTML, which contains the string, cannot be modified.  I'm only trying to figure out how to change $regex

Comment: `href="rs(\d+)/` the `/` looks like a typo for `"`

Comment: Not the original HTML, the argument to `regex_test()`.

Comment: E.g. `regex_test($s, 'rs\\d+ was merged...')`

Comment: Or use a regexp literal as the argument to `regex_test`, instead of a string.

Comment: And my 2 cents - are always do `xx` at the end of a regex - and use `\s*+` instead of literal spaces (very common case of failure in my experience). (and also if you go that route - `\b` between words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the trailing `/` character in the `$regex`, which should either be omitted or changed to `"`

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $s = '      rs577952184 was merged into
      
        <a target="_blank"
           href="rs59222162">rs59222162</a>
      
';

my $re = qr/rs\d+ was merged into\s+<a target="_blank"\s+href="rs(\d+)">rs\d+<\/a>/;

regex_test($s,$re);

exit 0;

sub regex_test {
    my $string = shift;
    my $regex  = shift;
    
    say $string =~ m/$regex/s 
        ? "$string matches $regex"
        : "$string doesn't match $regex";
}
```

Output

```
      rs577952184 was merged into

        <a target="_blank"
           href="rs59222162">rs59222162</a>

 matches (?^:rs\d+ was merged into\s+<a target="_blank"\s+href="rs(\d+)">rs\d+</a>)
```